# Как правильно написать - "жироуловитель" или "жироулавливатель"?

Tags: правописание

Как правильно - "жироуловитель" или "жироулавливатель"?

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря: УЛОВИТЕЛЬ, приспособление для улавливания чего-л. У. пыли, золы, газа.

Хотя в текстах встречаются обе формы, "жироуловитель" кажется более точным обозначением и применяется чаще, например: Жироуловитель (жироулавливатель) под мойку используется как первоначальная очистная единица.

Также общий термин "уловитель", образованный от глагола сов. вида, применяется в большинстве случаев:

Зерно просыпается через решетку, установленную под приемным битером, и попадает в брезентовый уловитель.

Вращаясь, твердые частицы прижимаются центробежными силами к гладкой поверхности конуса и с каплями жидкости стекают через нижнее отверстие в уловитель.

Answer (score 1):

Вот хочу посоветовать сайт очень простой в использовании https://polyfacture.ru/zhirouloviteli/

Словарь указывает на синонимию в употреблении слов, оканчивающихся на *-улавливатель*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]